# Transforming nonlinear optimization problem into linear problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linearization

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \dfrac{2x_1 - 2x_2 - 2}{x_1 + 3x_2 + 4}\\ \text{subject to} & -x_1 + x_2 \leq 4\\ & 2x_1 + x_2 \leq 14\\ & x_2 \leq 6\\ & x_1 \geq 0\\ & x_2 \geq 0\end{array}$$

I want to obtain a linear problem by introducing new variables. Then it will be possible to solve it. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to introduce these variables.

Comment: Can you please give the source of this problem? Thanks!

Comment: There exists $\color{blue}{\texttt{no optimal solution}}$. For any valid  value of $x_1$ a greater value of $x_1$ is always valid, which makes the value of the objective function larger.

Comment: In general it is a good idea to look at a (mathematical) problem carefully before thinking of an algorithm.

Comment: @callculus lets pretend we treat everything except $x_1$ to be constant, the quotient will then stagnate at 2 as the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x_1\to \infty}\frac{2x_1+c_1}{x_1+c_2} = 2$, which clearly does not grow unbounded.

Comment: @mathreadler But don´t we need $x_1 \in \mathbb R$ for an optimal solution ?

Comment: I made a mistake in a second constraint. I corrected it, so now it is ok.

Comment: @callculus : Ehm... What? You seem confused.

Comment: @mathreadler What? What do you mean? Anyway the OP changed the question. So my comment was not useless.

Comment: Changing the question after having gotten answers is usually not tolerated on the site. Let us see what happens. Any way inequalities are not defined if you are not working in $\mathbb R$ so your comment still makes no sense.

Comment: @mathreadler But it would be more clever to think and ask before posting an answer. And really you say infinity is in $\mathbb R$? Your comments are getting more and more senseless.

Comment: Your comments are much more senseless. A good method should work regardless of what would happen in the particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when we have

$min z=\frac{px+a}{qx+d}$

s.t. $Ax<=b $ , $x>=0$

We changed problem by $z=\frac{1}{qx+d}$ and $y=zx$

Then the original problem changed to:

$ min z= py+az$

s.t.$Ay<=bz$

$qy+dz=1$

$y>=0$

$z>=0$

Comment: This is known as a Charnes-Cooper transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce new variables together with equations: $$\cases{x_3 = \phantom{2}x_1+3x_2+4\\x_4 = 2x_1-2x_2-2}$$and you will get:

$$\min\left\{\frac{x_4}{x_3}\right\}$$

which will be achieved (by monotonicity of the $\log$ family of functions), when:

$$\min\{\log(x_4)-\log(x_3)\}$$

Which indeed is linear in the new variables $\cases{x_6=\log(x_4)\\x_5=\log(x_3)}$ : $\min\{1\cdot x_6 - 1\cdot x_5\}$

Now what remains is to find a way to represent the logarithmic function linearly of some suitable representation of $x_3,x_4$ and to linearly fuse all the variables and the constraints. That is a separate (but even more important) problem! Especially if we want to be able to linearize more advanced non-linear functions in the future.